# htaccess rewrite - probably simple

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm looking for a way to rewrite my URLs and am checking what htaccess can do for me.

I want to rewrite

```
domain.com/index.php?page=myPage&name=test
```

to

```
domain.com/myPage/?name=test
```

All tutorials I've found only shows how to do complex things but something as simple as this, isn't to be found anywhere.

What I have only rewrites "myPage" to "page=myPage" and ignores what I put after "?" in my URL

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Notice that "name=test" could be anything (id=1, mode=edit, foo=bar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the flag for "query string append" by changing `[L]` to `[QSA,L]`

Source: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa